# Qt 5.4 - QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT

Tags: qt

Switching from Qt 5.3 to 5.4, suddenly my custom message handler is receiving neither the line number nor file name from Qt libraries that use qDebug(), qWarning() and qCritical().

The docs indicate that this was a change in Qt 5.4.  To get this information you have to explicitly define QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT.  So I did.  I downloaded the Qt 5.4 source code, configured it, compiled it, and set my code to use the new libraries.  The problem is, I'm still not getting the file name and line number info.

Here's how I'm configuring the Qt build:

```
configure.bat -platform win32-msvc2010 -debug-and-release -nomake examples -nomake tests -opensource -opengl desktop -c++11 -no-strip -D QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You don't need to rebuild Qt with that define, you need to build your application with that define enabled.**

The rationale behind the behaviour change is quite simple: **you may not want sensitive information (function names, line numbers) to be leaked** in debug or warning outputs that your application may have.

Therefore, **by default, in release builds the function names and line numbers are wiped out**. On the other hand, they're still available in debug builds, so you may actually avoid using that define and simply recompile your app in debug mode.

---

**If you want to enable function names and line numbers even for release builds**, open the `.pro` file of your application and add something like

```
DEFINES += QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT
```

Then rerun `qmake` and rebuild the entire app.

Comment: Yes I have it defined in my application but I'd like it to be defined for all Qt libraries too.  I'm writing a test program to see exactly where a certain printer is causing Qt to crash and to further debug that issue.  I want to run everything is release mode to eliminate debug vs release as a factor.

Comment: My configuration options were correct but I wasn't running qmake before recompiling the Qt source code.